# How do I label my array using javascript from values from another array?

Tags: javascript, zapier

Hi I'm using javascript in zapier and need to label my output.

So I'd like the label to be "arraytitle" and the data to be "arraysku"
Eg title1 : sku1 , title2 :sku2
But it just shows the words title1 and not the value from the array?

```js
let arraysku = inputData.array
let arraytitle = inputData.arraytitle
let sku = []
let title = []

//arraysku = arraysku.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
arraysku = arraysku.split(',')
console.log(arraysku)

//arraytitle = arraytitle.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
arraytitle = arraytitle.split(',')
console.log(arraytitle)

let { 0: sku1, 1: sku2, 2: sku3, 3: sku4, 4: sku5, 5: sku6 } = arraysku
let { 0: title1, 1: title2, 2: title3, 3: title4, 4: title5, 5: title6 } = arraytitle
let skuinfo = { title1: sku1,  sku2: sku2, sku3: sku3, sku4: sku4, sku5: sku5, sku6: sku6 }

for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  sku.push({ id: i, info : skuinfo })
}

//console.log(coursename, skuinfo)
output = sku
```

Comment: Provide your `inputData`

Comment: Please explain your code and insert a fully working snippet

Comment: Try `skuinfo[title1] = sku1`

Comment: *"Eg title1 : sku1 , title2 :sku2"* then `let skuinfo = { title1: sku1,  sku2: sku2, sku3: sku3, sku4: sku4, sku5: sku5, sku6: sku6 }` should be `let skuinfo = { title1: sku1,  title2: sku2, title3: sku3, title4: sku4, title5: sku5, title6: sku6 }`

Comment: Thank you @holydragon  - this worked - skuinfo[title1] = sku1